# Altera Cyclone II Quartus II JTAG Programming Error

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, jtag, quartus, cyclone

I'm trying to program a Cyclone II I bought [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LEMKR92) using Quartus II 13.0sp1 on Arch Linux. I'm trying to program it with a very simple Verilog program with three inputs and two outputs and a few simple logic functions. I selected the proper model (EP2C5T144C8), assigned the pins to the inputs/outputs, compiled, and ran the programmer. I am using a JTAG USB blaster. When I run `jtagconfig`, I receive the following output

```
1) USB-Blaster [2-1.6]
    020B10DD   EP2C5
```

However, when I try to program the .sof file created by the compiler, I receive the following error.

```
Error (209015): Can't configure device. Expected JTAG ID code 0x020B10DD for device 1, but found JTAG ID code 0x000310D9.
```

If I run the programmer multiple times, I often get different values for the ID code that it found. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: What programmer are you using to program the device?  A lot of these low-cost boards are supplied with fake "USB Blaster" JTAG interfaces that may not be quite up to the job -- see e.g. https://hackaday.io/project/92800-fpga-experiments/log/142895-dirt-cheap-usb-blaster-clones-considered-harmful

Comment: If you're getting different codes each time, there is either a dodgy connection somewhere, or the device is toast.

Comment: @Jules I bought a $10 one thats featured on the same page on Amazon.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I figure it probably is, but what throws me off is that the device ID in the `jtagconfig` command shows up properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the solution is similar to what I had seen online; it's a power supply problem. Getting a proper 5 V power supply solved the issue, and the FPGA is now programmable and fully functioning.